# python not running through the correct if statements

Tags: python, if-statement

the trend date is hard coded and set to be 06-01-2023 but the code is only running through the last if statement and not running through what it needs to be running through

the first row on the excel sheet image has effective date to be 01-01-2019 so the trenddate.year - effective date.year should be 4 and should run through the second if statement but it does not.

Comment: Please post all code as text, no images. And BTW your expressions return uncalled `lambda` functions which are always considered `True`.

Comment: What's the deal with all those `lambda`s? What were you trying to achieve there?

Comment: You're never calling your lambdas, and I'm not sure why they're there anyway.

Comment: someone sent you some nonsense... you can probably try remove all the `lambda x: ` to convert the useless lambdas into ordinary expressions and then wrap the whole thing in a function def that takes `x` as an argument

Comment: @Anentropic how would I do that, i am pretty new to python stuff like this

Comment: Judging by the lines like `data.apply(lambda x: (13 - x["EffectiveDate"].month), axis = 1)` it appears that `data` is a Pandas dataframe (e.g. see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) ...I am not very familiar with Pandas, maybe there is a 'pandas' way to rewrite the code that makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as has been suggested, remove the lambdas in the if statements (not in the `data.apply`s though), and change them to `if (trenddate.year - x["EffectiveDate"].year == 5):` (the brackets are not needed but you may keep them).

Secondly, all of the if statements seem to be indented so they lie under the scope of the first one, meaning they would never be called as upon the occasions that the first if statement is called, the subsequent ones' conditions will not be met. These should be unindented to match the first if statement.

I would also like to point out that this whole thing could probably be simplified down into a single for loop, like this (make sure I've not made some grievous error though):

```
for i in range(5):
    if (trenddate.year - data["EffectiveDate"].year == 5 - i):
        for j in range(5):
            if j < i:
                data["TrendMonths" + str(j + 1)] = 0
            if j == i:
                data["TrendMonths" + str(j + 1)] = data.apply(lambda x: (13 - x["EffectiveDate"].month),axis = 1)
            if j > i:
                data["TrendMonths" + str(j + 1)] = 12
        data["TrendMonths6"] = 11 - trenddate.month
```

Comment: this code makes sense but then i believe the x in the second line is not defined and causes an error

Comment: Ah, I thought that might happen. I've edited it to replace that `x` with `data`, which seems to point to your table as I suspected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my two cents.

First as noted in the comments, don't use the `lambda`s in the if conditions, you never called them, and `bool(lambda x: x)` is always `True`. You want to use the expressions as conditions, just remove the `lambda`s (but not inside apply call).

Secondly you wrongly nested the if conditions inside the top level, if the difference is not 5, the other conditions won't be checked. Move them out of the first condition.

And `data["TrendMonths6"] = 11 - trenddate.month` is inside all conditions, move it out of the conditional blocks.

Then you can do what you did in a single for loop to use only one if block to do the job. You just need to subtract the number from 6, the difference concatenated with `"TrendMonths"` is the key to do the `data.apply` thing, then set all keys before it to 0 and after it (and before 6) to 12.

Finally since the number can only have exactly one value, when it is found, all other equality checks are not needed, we should break the loop, since if we don't, Python will just keep checking the other numbers and do unnecessary work.

Here is the code:

```
for i in (5, 4, 3, 2, 1):
    if trenddate.year - x["EffectiveDate"].year == i:
        j = 6 - i
        data[f"TrendMonths{j}"] = data.apply(lambda x: (13 - x["EffectiveDate"].month),axis = 1)
        for a in range(1, j):
            data[f"TrendMonths{a}"] = 0
        for b in range(j + 1, 6):
            data[f"TrendMonths{b}"] = 12
        break
data["TrendMonths6"] = 11 - trenddate.month
```